# How to display the number of users visiting a Superset dashboard within a time interval on Prometheus?

Tags: python, python-3.x, prometheus, apache-superset

I want to monitor Superset dashboards and have planned to use my own custom Python exporter along with Prometheus. I am setting a gauge to value 1 every time a dashboard is logged to be visited by some user. My target plot is: y-axis as count of visits, x-axis as time and dashboard_id as the plot.

My Python exporter is as follows:

```
class DashboardMonitor:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dashboard_gaguge_map = defaultdict(Gauge)

    def create_dashboard_gauges(self, dashboards_list):
        for dashboard_id, dashboard_name in dashboards_list.items():
            gauge_name = 'dashboard_{}_gauge'.format(dashboard_id)
            gauge_description = dashboard_name
            dashboard_gauge = Gauge(gauge_name, gauge_description)
            self.dashboard_gaguge_map[dashboard_id] = dashboard_gauge

    def get_dashboard_gauge(self, dashboard_id):
        return self.dashboard_gaguge_map.get(dashboard_id, None)

    def set_dashboard_gauge(self, dashboard_id):
        dashboard_gauge = self.get_dashboard_gauge(dashboard_id)
        dashboard_gauge.set(1)
```

My current query on Prometheus is:
`sum(rate(dashboard_1_gauge[1m]))  * 60` that plots the following:
[image]

I am not confident whether the plot displays what I want it to be or whether the method of setting the gauge as 1 every time I encounter that dashboard in the logs is the optimal way to do this.

How do I do this?

Comment: Sorry for off-topic. Where do you call your `set_dashboard_gauge`? We have the same need to monitor user activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate, `rate` should only be used with counters, not gauges.

I'd change this metric into a counter and then use `sum(rate(dashboard_1_counter[1m]))` to chart the use rate in accesses per second or `sum(increase(dashboard_1_counter[1m]))` if you want to get a count of accesses in each time bucket, like `1m` in this case.

Comment: What should I do if that 1m is not fixed? Like, you opt for a time period and in that time period, you get to see the total visits made to that dashboard. How would you do this?

Comment: Use `$__interval` in place of 1m. It's the granularity or resolution of display in Grafana, usually set automatically, but you can adjust the minimums with `Min step` and `Min time interval` in the query options.

Comment: Hey, thank you but I am planning to track the number of visits within a time interval(dynamic) and not the rate. How would I do that? As you can see in my question, my aim is to plot the number of visits v/s time.

Comment: Grafana time range is split into intervals. Normally interval is set automatically, depending on the size of the screen, resolution and such. But you can control the minimums as said above.

As also said, use `sum(increase(dashboard_1_counter[$__interval]))`. ìncrease()` function gives you the difference between end point and start point of each interval. And `rate()`is just ìncrease()` divided by the timespan of each interval.

Comment: So, plotting `sum(increase(dashboard_1_counter[$__interval]))`. ìncrease()` will give you the number of visits in each interval.
But prerequisite for all that is that your metric work as a counter and not as gauge. See `sum(increase(dashboard_1_counter[1m]))`. ìncrease()`.

Comment: See https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter